# problems with .map() to display data from api

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So, im fetching data from an api and when i console log the response im able to see the api as expected. Im storing the data in states but whenever i want to iterate the state to return the data in the screen i get the map undefined error. I have tried evrything i found here but nothing works. Please help me with this. Thank you

```
...
const [state, setState] = useState([]);
  let headers = new Headers();
  headers.set("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password));

  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, []);

  const getData = async () => {
    const a = await fetch(url, { method: "GET", headers: headers });
    const response = await a.json();
    setState(response);
    console.log(response);
  };
  // console.log(state)

  return (
    <div>
      {state.data.map((test) => (
        <div>
          <p>{test.place}</p>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default FetchApi;
```

api

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "type": "Other",
            "place": "US",
            "attributes": [
                {
                    "displayName": "name",
                    "value": "Jenna"
                },
                {
                    "displayName": "Gender",
                    "value": "Female"
                },
                {
                    "displayName": "Phone_number",
                    "value": "+12346543"
                }
            ]
        }
        
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the raw response, so first

```
// change this
const [state, setState] = useState([]);

// to this
const [state, setState] = useState({});
```

because in the first render, `state.data` is `undefined`, so make sure to handle that case

```js
return (
  <div>
    {(state.data || []).map((test) => (
      <div>
        <p>{test.place}</p>
      </div>
    ))}
  </div>
);
```

Comment: Thank you it worked. Had no idea about this approach.